# Using multiprocessing to compute shortest path on a graph

Tags: python, dictionary, multiprocessing, shortest-path

I currently have a shortest path algorithm that receives as inputs the Graph and a Node of origin, and returns the costs for all nodes in the graph plus the tree (precedents for each node).
   The graph is a dictionary, so are the costs AND the tree.

Since I have to compute the shortest path trees with origins in all nodes, it is only natural to do it in parallel (as the trees are independent of each other).

I'm doing it with the use of a pool of workers using the multiprocessing and appending the results to a list (so I want a list of dictionaries).

It runs without errors, but the interesting part is that the processing time does not change with the number of workers (NO CHANGE AT ALL).

Any insight on why does that happen will be mostly appreciated.  Code follows below.

```
from LoadData import *
from ShortestPathTree import shortestPath
from time import clock, sleep
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process, cpu_count, Queue


def funcao(G,i):
    costs, pred=shortestPath(G,i)
    return pred


def main():

    #loads the graph
    graph="graph.graph"
    G = load_graph(graph)

    # loads the relevant nodes (CENTROIDS)
    destinations="destinations.graph"
    DEST = load_relevant_nodes(destinations)

    f = open('output_parallel.out','w')
    start=clock()


    pool=Pool()

    resultados=[]
    def adder(value):
        resultados.append(value)


    #for i in range(len(DEST)):
    for i in range(486):
        pool.apply_async(funcao, args=(G,DEST[i]), callback=adder)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()


    print clock()-start
    print >> f, resultados
    print >> f, 'seconds: '+ str(clock()-start)
```

Comment: Is it any faster if you replace `pool=Pool()` with `pool=Pool(processes=4)`?

Comment: It's not likely, but it's possible that everything's serializing on, say, the `apply_async` callback. Try `imap_unordered` or `map_async` instead. Actually, it looks like you're just manually emulating `map`, so, even simpler, just try that…

Comment: Also, can you give us a complete runnable sample that doesn't require your custom loading and graph processing code, but does demonstrate your problem? I tried to fake out those functions, and my version very definitely seems to be a problem with your use of `apply_async` (it takes 1.12s with pool=1, 1.14s with pool=4… but when I switch to `map` it's 0.83s with pool=1, 0.41s with pool=4), but it's hard to guess whether that's true for your test case.

Comment: @abarnert, I tried to use map, but could not figure out how to provide both arguments to the function (kept getting an error that the number of arguments to the function was wrong). Can you provide the test code you used?

Comment: You can't pass two arguments to the function in `map`—but you can pass a single `tuple` with two values, which is just as good (as long as you can do a trivial rewrite or wrap of the function). For example: `def funcao(Gi): consts, pred=shortestPath(*Gi); return pred`, then `pool.map(funcao, ((G,DEST[i]) for i in range(486)))`.

Comment: Two more questions to rule out more unlikely but not impossible causes: First, how long does one call of `funcao` take, and what platform are you on? If the algorithm is short enough, and you're on a platform with slow process startup and teardown (like Windows), it's conceivable that starting 8 processes instead of 1 (or 0) is enough to counter the benefits of running the jobs in parallel. Second, is `funcao` actually CPU-bound, or is most of its time spent waiting elsewhere? (Even if it's not doing any obvious I/O, using enough memory to swap can make you disk bound…)

Comment: @abarnert I'm on Windows 7 64. The function Funcao is definitely CPU bound. It is a shortest path algorithm that computes the shortest path tree from one node to all other nodes on the network. The implementation of pool.map did not change my results. When I look at my task manager I see that only one process is running at maximum (25%) and the others are at around 4%, so they are not really being used or my process is not CPU bound and the back and fourth of information with the function is the problem.  The graph is big not small though

Comment: Well, try with `map` (with a `chunksize` of 1) or `imap` and see if that changes. If it's still 25/4/4/4, we can rule out your scheduling/dispatch code. Another way to rule that out is to add some logging (just add `print(os.getpid())` to the top of `funcao`) to make sure the processes really are all getting jobs to work on.

Comment: One more idea: I don't know what your input looks like, but is it possible that one job is 6x heavier-duty than the other jobs? In that case, the results you're seeing would make sense. (If this is a possibility, but you're not sure, is there anything obviously predictive about the inputs, like `len(G)`, that you can throw into the `print` statement in `funcao`?)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that @abarnert nailed it on the head on he asked how long did each call take. There was a problem in the data being entered that made each call EXTREMELY easy to answer, so the overhead of sending the tasks for multiple workers compensated the improvement in performance.

```
The results I get now that the input data was corrected are:
```

1 core:  185.0s
2 cores: 111.2s
3 cores:  96.6s
4 cores:  87.5s

Running on a Dual Core Hyperthreaded i7 620M Lenovo T410 laptop (Win 7 64 bits, Python 2.7.3)

Thanks to @abarnert for the GREAT insight!